# How do I allow nginx regex ONLY on subsection of a url?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config, proxypass

I have a few urls, `id` is a variable.

Everything up to `/purchases/id` needs to proxy_pass, and everything after this section of the url to not proxy_pass and continue as normal.  Below is how this should work:

```
/purchases                  - allow proxy_pass
/purchases/id               - allow proxy_pass
/purchases/id/terms         - continue as normal
/purchases/id/terms/accept  - continue as normal
/purchases/id/terms/cancel  - continue as normal
/purchases/id/terms/return  - continue as normal
```

Here is the nginx configuration. Currently all urls are passing to proxy_pass.

```
    location ~ ^/purchases {
      proxy_pass     https://myurl.com;
    }
    location ~ ^/purchases/(\d+)$ {
      proxy_pass     https://myurl.com;
    }
```

Is there anything obvious that is being missed?
Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else with this problem. The issue was not with regex or the rules.  It was the order of the rules.

The first rule was catching everything, and then nginx had no need to apply the second rule.

Below fixed the issue:

```
    location ~ ^/purchases/(\d+)$ {
      proxy_pass     https://myurl.com;
    }
    location ~ ^/purchases {
      proxy_pass     https://myurl.com;
    }
```